# Best practice and efficient equals() override method

Tags: java, intellij-idea

The first one is the code that I have generated using intelliJ IDEA, and the other one is the code that I wrote by referring to the Oracle tutorial.

Which one would be the most practical and more efficient?

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

    Member member = (Member) o;

    if (!email.equals(member.email)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o instanceof Member) {
        return email.equals(((Member) o).getEmail());
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: IMO I would use the second for readability. About which one is *more efficient*, I won't even bother unless it shows to be a performance problem proven by the usage of a profiler.

Comment: The first one has the advantage that does not break the `equals` contract if you create a subclass of your current class.

Comment: Or you can do `return (o instanceof Member) && email.equals(((Member) o).getEmail());`

Comment: I agree with both Luiggi and SJuan. Note that IntelliJ lets you specify whether you want to allow subclasses when you ask it to generate `equals`; "no" is the safer option for the reasons others have linked to.

Comment: @yshavit that depends on the design, there's not an absolute decision on this.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza True, but if I need to design for extendability in a way that doesn't just require making `equals` and `hashCode` final (in which case `Class#equals` and `instanceof` essentially equivalent), then the autogenerated code is rarely the right code.

Comment: @yshavit I won't say it's right or bad, that depends on personal opinion and the *rightness* will be defined by each specific case. Also, this can be defined in a programming standard based on the experience gained in old projects.

Comment: I like this article con the subject http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html. And, as other people have pointed, my previous comment is not relevant is the class is `final` (in that case, `instanceof` and class equality give exactly the same result)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding efficience they are equivalent efficient. There is not an impact on performance either you use the first or the second. I would prefer the first though, since it "protects" you from comparing Objects to Objects from Subclasses, which leads to strange, not expected and not consistent results.

Answer (score 1):

If I have a `class B extends Member` then `B` is an `instanceof` `Member` therefor it is error prone in many cases. First solution is the best. Choose the one generated by IDE.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for generated because:

- You will not make error
- It is faster to code
- There is no `instanceof` operator

Answer (score 0):

I'd pick the one generated by the IDE cause it is easier to create and is less likely to contain errors. In those rare cases that it does not suffice, you'll know what changes are needed to suit your specific purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is (IMHO) the more correct.
The second one returns true also for your class' subclasses, which may not be what you want... (see http://www.artima.com/lejava/articles/equality.html)